# Hide or disable actionButton() after it is clicked and show it again with the click of other actionButton() in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

In the `shiny` app below I have an `actionButton()` which when pressed creates a second `actionButton()`. Now I want when this 2nd `actionButton()` is pressed to be hidden again and be displayed again only when the 1st `actionButton` is clicked again and so on...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Subset Iris Dataset"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    actionButton("subset_button", "Subset Data"),
    uiOutput("second")
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$subset_button,{
    output$second<-renderUI({
      actionButton("act","action")
    })
    
  })
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a `conditionalPanel` using the condition `input.subset_button !== input.act`. However, this will only work when the first button is not pressed again while the second button is displayed. To handle this case, requires some more effort. In the code below I use a `reactiveVal` to store the status of the subset button and a `reactive` to ensure that the value of the status is at most one ahead of the second button's value. Finally, I use `outputOptions` to make the status available for use in the condition of the `conditionalPanel`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Subset Iris Dataset"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    actionButton("subset_button", "Subset Data"),
    conditionalPanel(
      "output.status_subset !== input.act",
      actionButton("act", "action")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  status_subset <- reactiveVal(0)
  output$status_subset <- reactive({
    status_subset(input$subset_button)
    isolate({
      if (status_subset() > input$act) status_subset(input$act + 1)
    })
    status_subset()
  })
  outputOptions(output, "status_subset", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```